# Remove some numbers from a list of data with Python

Tags: python

I have this list of data:

```
a = [552.5, 560.0, 582.5, 532.5, 575.5, 985.5, 510.0, 125.0]
```

I want to remove from the list the data with the number `5` after the dot `.5`. Such as: `552.5`, `582.5`, `532.5`, ... And get:

```
a = [560.0, 510.0, 125.0]
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Other than filtering for near-integers?

Comment: The OP is probably in a region that uses a comma for the decimal separator.

Comment: Do you want only integers remaining or only things that aren't x.5? eg would 343.3 be kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick one that you like:

```
>>> a = [552.5, 560.0, 582.5, 532.5, 575.5, 985.5, 510.0, 125.0]

>>> [i for i in a if not str(i).split('.')[1].startswith('5')]
[560.0, 510.0, 125.0]

>>> [i for i in a if str(i).split('.')[1][0] != '5']
[560.0, 510.0, 125.0]
>>>
```

Comment: No need say thanks here :). But if an answer is helpful, please accept it. Check our [tour] to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension to pick only the numbers which isn't endswith `.5`.

```
>>> a = [552.5, 560.0, 582.5, 532.5, 575.5, 985.5, 510.0, 125.0]
>>> [i for i in a if not str(i).endswith('.5')]
[560.0, 510.0, 125.0]
>>>
```

Comment: This would fail if there is more than one decimal, like 552.51.

Comment: then `[i for i in a if '.5' not in str(i)]`

Answer (score 1):

In a very fancy way without converting to string:)

```
import math
filter(lambda x: math.modf(x)[0] != 0.5, a)
```

I think other suggestions with converting to string are more convenient, just another not really standard variant if you are curious.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter them out by checking each value against its `int()` call (`int()` truncates the value after the decimal):

```
a = [552.5, 560.0, 582.5, 532.5, 575.5, 985.5, 510.0, 125.0]
result = [value for value in a if value==int(value)]
```

Comment: Although the OP did not have any examples where the decimal was not .0 or .5, removing anything where it isn't .0 is quite distinct from what the OP requested, which is removing only the ones where the first digit after the decimal is exactly 5.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the list:

```
filter(lambda x: not str(x).endswith('.5'), lst)
```

or truncate it and compare with the number (this will filter all that are not `.0`even for `.3333` for example)

```
import math
filter(lambda x: x == math.trunc(x), lst)

>>> a = [552.5, 560.0, 582.5, 532.5, 575.5, 985.5, 510.0, 125.0]
>>> filter(lambda x: x == math.trunc(x), a)
[560.0, 510.0, 125.0]
```